# How to do a line selection in fiji (imagej) using specified coords

Tags: imagej, fiji

How to select a line in an image using ImageJ/Fiji by setting its start and end points? As in not drawing it over the image, but inputting the coordinates directly somewhere.

Comment: This is easily the silliest sounding question i've ever asked on SO.

Comment: But very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open script editor, select IJ1 macro and then type the code below and then run.

```
makeLine(1, 1, 100, 100);
```

This will create a line ROI between (1,1) and (100, 100).

See
https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#makeLine